# During cucumber testing Factory already registered: user (FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, factory-bot

in gemfile. i have added factory_girls_rails.

```
group :test do
  gem 'cucumber-rails'
  gem 'capybara'
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

in features/support/env.rb require factories from spec/factories.rb

```
require 'cucumber/rails'
require "#{Rails.root}/spec/factories"
```

in spec/factories.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    first_name "John"
    last_name  "Doe"
    admin false
  end
end
```

and in spec/spec_helper i have require require 'factory_girl_rails'

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'rspec/autorun'
require 'factory_girl_rails'

# Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc, 
# in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
```

now i got following error ...plz suggest me any body as well also write step defination for use this factories.rb.

manish@ubuntu:~/change/test_cucumber$ cucumber features/sign_up.feature 
Factory already registered: user (FactoryGirl::DuplicateDefinitionError)
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl        /decorator.rb:10:in `method_missing'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/decorator/disallows_duplicates_registry.rb:6:in`register'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:65:in `block in register_factory'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:64:in`each'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl.rb:64:in `register_factory'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:20:in`factory'
/home/manish/change/test_cucumber/spec/factories.rb:2:in `block in <top (required)>'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in`instance_eval'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:49:in `run'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/factory_girl-4.2.0/lib/factory_girl/syntax/default.rb:7:in`define'
/home/manish/change/test_cucumber/spec/factories.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in`require'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in`load_dependency'
/home/manish/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
/home/manish/change/test_cucumber/features/support/env.rb:8:in`'

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think requiring factory_girl_rails already loads the factory files, so requiring again in your support/env file is causing a conflict. Delete the second line in support/env.rb and see what happens.

Comment: Yes i got solution by replace require "#{Rails.root}/spec/factories" by require 'factory_girl_rails'. now it's working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case in `rails_helper.rb` I used `FactoryGirl.find_definitions`, which turned out to be redundant.